# iPhone music sync (iOS 6.1.2), is it possible yet?

Tags: sync, music, iphone

Is it yet possible to synchronize music?
I know about questions like these:

- [Is it possible yet to synchronise music to an iPhone running iOS 5/6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218838/is-it-possible-yet-to-synchronise-music-to-an-iphone-running-ios-5-6)
- [sync music with a iPhone 4 iOS 6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198866/iphone-4-ios-6-sync-with-ubuntu-12-04)

Is it possible yet? Seeing, both questions are ~3 months old.

Comment: I am not aware of any software that allows you to synchronize without the use of iTunes, but you could always use VirtualBox, and then installing iTunes from that.

Comment: Have you tried to install iTunes using Wine ?

Comment: Check http://freshtutorial.com/install-itunes-ubuntu-linux/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/166903/how-do-i-install-itunes

Comment: Check also doing so using RhythmBox as in its web page, it mentions the ability to sync music to and from iPod http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way of syncing music without owning a copy of windows or OSx. All the workarounds (that actually work!) use virtualbox, which presupposes you have a copy of windows. It seems iTunes run through PlayonLinux or WINE will not sync your device.

Best native functionality exists in Banshee. Very limited (deleting songs).